# No cookie shown while I have it in Resources/Cookies

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch

I am sending a http request and a cookie is send back. I can see the cookie name and it's value in Reources/Cookies/127.0.0.1/

Here is the problem: When I try to get the cookie on the web console by using `document.cookie` , there is no cookie and the result is empty `""`

Here is my http request by the use of Ext js.

```
new Ext.Application({
launch : function() {

    Ext.util.JSONP.request({
        url : 'host',
        params : {
            method : 'GET',
            username : 'userName',
            password : 'password',
            press : 'Login'
        }
    });     
}
});
```

I noticed that I can get the cookie on concole by `document.cookie` when I normally log-in on the website, but when I send the http request by this code, I can not get it on concole.

I appreciate if you provide me the solution of the problem as well as some explanation why/when this happens ?

Comment: Would you mind providing us with the relevant parts your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your script execute at the domain you are setting cookie for? Executing document.cookie in console returns cookie for the domain it is executed at.

If you are sending a request for the qalixa.com domain, the cookie is set for that domain, not 127.0.0.1.

If you are debugging a site at your localhost, you should send a request to "https://127.0.0.1/ce/dynamic/ce/auth.html" then.

Comment: what he is saying is that your page under localhost cannot read a cookie that was send from another domain(i.e. qalixa.com). its a browser security thing.

Comment: As far as I understood, the cookie is sent in HTTP headers, and there is no way to send it in ajax response text?

Comment: Then, if the site does not provide any API functions for authorizing you are unable to detect if the cookies are set or not. However, if authorization is correct, you are able to send requests to site's server as an authorized user. Browser will send back cookie set by HTTP headers of that site with the requests.